# Automatically generating storage setter

Tags: storage

When declaring `storage` items inside the runtime, we can automatically generate getters to query that storage item, for example ([https://docs.substrate.io/v3/runtime/storage/#declaring-`storage-items`](https://docs.substrate.io/v3/runtime/storage/#declaring-%60storage-items%60))`:

```rust
#[pallet::storage]
#[pallet::getter(fn some_primitive_value)]
pub(super) type SomePrimitiveValue<T> = StorageValue<_, u32, ValueQuery>;
```

Is there a simple way to generate a setter in the same way? While a simple setter is likely undesirable on all storage items, it would be handy to have a shorthand way to set storage values from root or signed accounts:

```rust
#[pallet::root_setter(fn some_primitive_value)]
#[pallet::signed_setter(fn some_primitive_value)]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is not a way with our macros, and generally I would suggest not even to use this feature.

When you include `#[pallet::getter(fn some_primitive_value)]` all that is happening is the generation of the following function:

```rust
fn some_primitive_value() -> u32 {
    SomePrimitiveValue::<T>::get()
}
```

So really you have not saved much code writing, and you have created some macro magic abstraction.

Similarly, if you wanted to write a "setter", you can just write:

```rust
fn set_some_primitive_value(value: u32) {
    SomePrimitiveValue::<T>::put(value)
}
```

Comment: So using the `pallet::getter` macro is fully optional?

Comment: yes. it is exactly equivalent to writing the function I wrote above inside `imp<T: Config> for Pallet<T>`

Comment: Yes, this is also the practice adopted by Phala Network